# R: Efficient way to return sums of products (compatible with JAGS)

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, sum, jags

I am attempting to calculate cell probabilities in an array that result from sums of products. This is part of a model I will run in JAGS within R. In this example, an object may be in one of 3 states. At each time interval it may remain in the same state or pass to one of the other states. With the example code below the starting state is 1 and the final state is 2. The array X is a state*state transition matrix (e.g. X[1,2] is the probability of an object in state 1 at time t being in state 2 at time t+1). Note that these are just made up numbers to test that test1 and test2 (see below) give the same result, since I know for certain that the hand calculation (test1) is correct.

```
    X <- array((0),dim=c(3,3))
X[1,1] <- 0.1
X[1,2] <- 0.2
X[1,3] <- 0.3
X[2,1] <- 0.4
X[2,2] <- 0.5
X[2,3] <- 0.6
X[3,1] <- 0.7
X[3,2] <- 0.8
X[3,3] <- 0.9
```

The example is simplified. I will ultimately have a separate state*state transition matrix for each time interval because transition is time dependent. I have also removed the probability of observation from the example for simplicity. With probability of observation included (as it will need to be in the end), each cell describes the probability of observing an object in the state and time of that cell *for the first time*. Each element of X consists of a survival parameter (for state i at time t) and transition parameter (for state i at t-1 to state j at time t). I will derive these components separately within the model and I don't think that part will be too difficult.

Back to the example as given below. I have calculated by hand (test1) the probability for state 2 at sample occasion 4 when the release state (the time interval before sample occasion 1) is 1. This calculation consists of the sums of products of all possible ways of getting to state 2 from state 1 over the time intervals.

```
test1 <-
    (X[1,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,2])+
    (X[1,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,2])+
    (X[1,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,2])+
      (X[1,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,2])+
      (X[1,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,2])+
      (X[1,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,2])+
        (X[1,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,2])+
        (X[1,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,2])+
        (X[1,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,2])+
           (X[1,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,2])+
           (X[1,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,2])+
           (X[1,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,2])+
             (X[1,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,2])+
             (X[1,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,2])+
             (X[1,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,2])+
                (X[1,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,2])+
                (X[1,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,2])+
                (X[1,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,2])+
                  (X[1,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,1]*X[1,2])+
                  (X[1,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,2]*X[2,2])+
                  (X[1,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,3]*X[3,2])+
                     (X[1,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,1]*X[1,2])+
                     (X[1,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,2]*X[2,2])+
                     (X[1,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,3]*X[3,2])+
                       (X[1,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,1]*X[1,2])+
                       (X[1,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,2]*X[2,2])+
                       (X[1,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,3]*X[3,2])  
test1 # = 0.9288
```

I have written a for loop that simplifies this calculation (test2) for each release state and recapture state. The problem is that over many more time intervals, my method will end up calculating the sums of products over an array with very many dimensions and I'm worried it will be very computationally expensive within JAGS.

```
test2 <- array((0),dim=c(3,3,3,3,3))
for (m in 1:3){
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    for (k in 1:3){
      for (s in 1:3){
      test2[m,i,j,k,s] <- X[m,i]*X[i,j]*X[j,k]*X[k,s]
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
sumtest2 <- sum(test2[1,,,,2]) # probability of state 2 at observation
                               # time 4 after release in state 1 at
                               # release time 1. 
    test2
    sumtest2 # = 0.9288 (the same as test1 and therefore the correct result)
```

My question is what might be a more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Thank you.

## --------------------------------

Thanks to Dex for the very useful answer. I have a follow up question, regarding time dependent transition matrices. The code above works great but I've not been able to use it for varying numbers of iterations where the transition matrix is different at each iteration.

For each release occasion *t* there are T-*t* recapture occasions (where T is total number of study years). I would like to matrix multiply with the matrices matching the time of first possible recapture up to the last recapture time.

This is part of the long version of what I would like to achieve:

```
# This long version does work, with lines for release occasion 1 
# and recapture occasions 1:4 only:
pr2 <- array((0), dim=c(3,3,4,4))
pr2[,,1,1] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,1])
pr2[,,1,2] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,1] %*% X[,,2])
pr2[,,1,3] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,1] %*% X[,,2] %*% X[,,3])
pr2[,,1,4] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,1] %*% X[,,2] %*% X[,,3] %*% X[,,4])
```

I have tried using an extra index for time and then using a for loop with matrix multiplication:

```
# With time dependence:
X <- array((0),dim=c(3,3,4))
X[1,1,1] <- 0.1
X[1,2,1] <- 0.2
X[1,3,1] <- 0.7
X[2,1,1] <- 0.25
X[2,2,1] <- 0.35
X[2,3,1] <- 0.4
X[3,1,1] <- 0.15
X[3,2,1] <- 0.25
X[3,3,1] <- 0.6
X[,,2] <- X[,,1]+0.05
X[,,3] <- X[,,1]-0.05
X[,,4] <- X[,,1]+0.1

# not working:    
library(expm)
    for (t in 1:4){
      for (j in t:4){
      pr1[,,t,j] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,j]%^%j)
      }
    }

# This also doesn't work:
library(expm)
for (t in 1:4){
  for (j in t:4){
    pr1[,,t,j] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (X[,,j]%^%1:j)
  }
}
```

I have also tried a list approach:

```
# List approach
# With time dependence:
X1 <- array((0),dim=c(3,3))
X1[1,1] <- 0.1
X1[1,2] <- 0.2
X1[1,3] <- 0.7
X1[2,1] <- 0.25
X1[2,2] <- 0.35
X1[2,3] <- 0.4
X1[3,1] <- 0.15
X1[3,2] <- 0.25
X1[3,3] <- 0.6
X2 <- X1+0.05
X3 <- X1-0.05
X4 <- X1+0.1

XT <- list(X1,X2,X3,X4)

pr1 <- array((0), dim=c(3,3,4,4))
# This also doesn't work:
library(expm)
for (t in 1:4){
  for (j in t:4){
    pr1[,,t,j] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (XT[[1:j]]%^%j)
  }
}
```

The following code shows a long way of calculating the probabilities in the time dependent array. It gives the correct values. Writing this out in full (with 23 release occasions and 23 recapture occasions, for 3 release/recapture states), while possible seems inefficient, especially if the analysis needs to be adapted later. This shows only the first four recapture occasions for individuals first released in the first release occasion. Each cell gives the probability of an individual being recaptured at that occasion *for the first time*. Recapture probability is given by p and so the probability of non-recapture is given by 1-p. In my analysis, T and p are parameters to be estimated. Their values are being defined here to make sure the mechanics are working as intended.

```
# Make a 3D transition matrix T where z-dimension is time
T_states <- 3
T_terms <- 4
Tz <- 4
T <- array(runif(T_states * T_states * Tz)/1.5, dim = c(T_states, T_states, Tz))

# Normalise by rows - this step ensures rows sum to 1
for (z in seq(Tz)) {
  T[, , z] <- T[, , z] / apply(T[, , z], 1, sum)
}

# state and time dependent recapture probability array [,recapture state,occasion]
# the first dimension is needed to repeat p across release states
p <- array((0),dim=c(3,3,4))
p[,1,1] <- 0.5
p[,1,2] <- 0.55
p[,1,3] <- 0.6
p[,1,4] <- 0.65
p[,2,1] <- 0.6
p[,2,2] <- 0.65
p[,2,3] <- 0.7
p[,2,4] <- 0.75
p[,3,1] <- 0.7
p[,3,2] <- 0.75
p[,3,3] <- 0.8
p[,3,4] <- 0.85

# Put them together (with 1-p for earlier recapture occasions):
pr2 <- array((0), dim=c(3,3,4,4))
pr2[,,1,1] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% (T[,,1]*p[,,1])
pr2[,,1,2] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% ((T[,,1]*(1-p[,,1])) %*% (T[,,2]*p[,,2]))
pr2[,,1,3] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% ((T[,,1]*(1-p[,,1])) %*% (T[,,2]*(1-p[,,2])) %*% (T[,,3]*p[,,1]))
pr2[,,1,4] <- diag(1, 3, 3) %*% ((T[,,1]*(1-p[,,1])) %*% (T[,,2]*(1-p[,,2])) %*% (T[,,3]*(1-p[,,3])) %*% (T[,,4]*p[,,4]))
pr2[,,1,]
```

I haven't been able to find a way of writing more efficient code for this that gives the same values (plenty of ways that give incorrect values).

Comment: there most definitely is

Comment: I'm confused by your transition matrix. Shouldn't the rowwise sum be 1 for all rows? Right now `X` implies that an object in state 3 can go to state 1 with 70% chance, state 2 with 80% chance and state 3 with 90% chance.

Comment: Hi Dex, I should have explained - those are just made up numbers to check that the for loop (or more efficient method) gives the same answer as the hand calculation. In the real model the elements in the transition matrix are to be estimated. As each element consists of the product of a survival probability and a transition probability, the rows will be less than 1 (they would equal 1 with 100% survival each year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with matrix multiplication. Transition matrices can be matrix-multiplied together to give a transition matrix over multiple iterations. For four iterations we do this four times:

`(X %*% X %*% X %*% X)`

You can also use the `%^%` operator from the `expm` package to do matrix exponentiation and save having to write it out.

To find out the likelihood of an object starting in state 1 ending up in state 2 after four iterations, we can represent it as a 1x3 matrix and multiply it by the transition matrix four times.

```
matrix(c(1, 0, 0), nrow = 1, ncol = 3) %*% (X %*% X %*% X %*% X)
```

This gives the probability of it being in the three states:

```
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
  [1,] 0.756 0.9288 1.1016
```

**Timing**

I made another example based off your code with a transition matrix that has sensible probabilities. Matrix multiplication is about 100 times faster than the for loop and gives the same answer.

```
library("microbenchmark")

X <- array((0),dim=c(3,3))
X[1,1] <- 0.1
X[1,2] <- 0.2
X[1,3] <- 0.7
X[2,1] <- 0.25
X[2,2] <- 0.35
X[2,3] <- 0.4
X[3,1] <- 0.15
X[3,2] <- 0.25
X[3,3] <- 0.6

microbenchmark(
  {test2 <- array((0),dim=c(3,3,3,3,3))
  for (m in 1:3){
    for (i in 1:3){
      for (j in 1:3){
        for (k in 1:3){
          for (s in 1:3){
          test2[m,i,j,k,s] <- X[m,i]*X[i,j]*X[j,k]*X[k,s]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sumtest2 <- sum(test2[1,,,,2])},
  matrix(c(1, 0, 0), nrow = 1, ncol = 3) %*% X %*% X %*% X %*% X
)
```

Comment: Thanks Dex, that's exactly what I was looking for: more efficient code and much faster!

Comment: I'm glad you found this useful, could you please mark the answer as accepted so it does not appear in the unanswered queues?

Comment: I have an update to my question regarding time-dependence as I've not been able to get this right. I have added this to the bottom of my original question showing what I'd like to achieve and what I've tried. It's hopefully straightforward but I'm now stumped. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. Is there a reason why you can't do this? https://gist.github.com/DexGroves/39a175b3453887a1ecc05f99f5cfb9c2

Comment: I have added more to my question to clarify the intended outcome. The link given doesn't provide the correct values because it gives probability of the final transition matrix without considering the preceding matrices that occur between first release and eventual recapture. Hopefully in the addition I've explained the issue better now.

Comment: I have accepted the first answer as it gives a perfect answer to my original question. The follow up is unresolved.